# I want to create a loader with still image in between the loader circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I want to create a loader with still image in between the loader
>   circle.  in this code the image is rotating along with loader i want 
>   the image to be still not rotating.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Loader with image</h2>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The -webkit- and -ms- prefixes are for browsers that do not support animation and transform properties.</p>

<div class="loader">
  <img id="drawerUserImage" class="img-circle" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/view-128.png"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what have you tried? - Do you have any idea how to achieve what you want? And having that idea what have you discovered, and what's the issue you encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change it something like this with using image in the wrapper elements background:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 152px;
  height: 152px;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.wrapper {
  background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/view-128.png') center no-repeat;
  background-size:50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {  
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try countering the rotating effect by creating identical animation for the img, just in opposite direction. However, a better option would be to change your DOM so that the image is not a child of animated parent.

```
.loader img {
  -webkit-animation: counter-spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: counter-spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
}
```